# Can't create new files to my folder that resides in plug-ins/components programatically

Tags: macos, file, core-audio, file-permissions

I have made an Audio Unit plugin ".component" and a folder for some custom data. The plugin is creating new MIDI files ".mid" to my folder in the component plugin folder but the DAW crashes when trying to save to my folder.

Isn't it possible to save and create files to a folder in the components folder from within the plugin programmatically? How can my plugin get permission to write to that folder without having the user to change/set folder permissions to be able to use my plugin?

Comment: What's the parent folder of this `plug-ins/components` folder?  If it's `/Library` then you won't be able to write to that folder.

Comment: Ah yes it is Library, thank you for the answer. I will have to rethink my approach again then, sad.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff should generally go in Application Support folders -- if your component is installed under `/Library`, in the local domain, you do this:

```
NSError *midiDataDirError = nil;
NSURL *localAppSupportDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
  URLForDirectory: NSApplicationSupportDirectory 
  inDomains: NSLocalDomainMask appropriateForURL: nil 
  create: YES error: &midiDataDirError ];

NSURL *midiDataDir = [localAppSupportDir 
  URLByAppendingPathComponent: MY_COMPONENT_NAME];
```